# No Outer Character or Necessary Indentation, yet Still Getting Unindent Error. Repl.it Python Discord Bot Special Commands

Tags: python, discord, bots

> I am making a Repl.it code for my discord bot. There's a certain command of which continuously gives me an error. The idea of the command is that it moves a person into a "jail" server if they ask for admin or moderator in general, as there is a specific channel for applications for those roles. It keeps giving me the "unindent doesn't match any outer indentation level" error and it seems no matter what I do it continues to give the same error.

```py
@bot.command()
async def give(ctx, *, arg):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
      await bot.say('youre going to *channel name*')~
  channel = bot.get_channel(*channel ID*)
  member = bot.get_member(0.subcommand_passed)
    await member.move_to(*channel name*)
```

> The error is marked by the "~"
> I've already checked and there is no space there or any character of any kind. I've looked online, checked Python guides, all to no avail. Can anyone help me with this? All help is appreciated.

> Post Statement: There is a post similar to this one from @Deleted-User, all though I have indeed tried it and it does not fix the issue. Please do not flag this for a duplicate, as it is not one.

Answer (score 0):

As the error is telling you, you haven't indented the code properly

```py
@bot.command()
async def give(ctx, *, arg):
   if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
       await bot.say('youre going to *channel name*')~
   channel = bot.get_channel(*channel ID*)
   member = bot.get_member(0.subcommand_passed)
   await member.move_to(*channel name*)
```

In your code, the `if` statement and the `channel` where in different levels of indentation. This throws an error as channel doesnt match any other indentation level.

Comment: Thank you so much. You don't know how long I've been trying to get an answer. I'm now getting an error somewhere else so if you could help me with that as well, it would be greatly appreciated. It will be found on my page

Comment: I don't see new questions on your profile, what do you mean by your page?

Comment: Just posted. Thank you.